# Local Postgres Server on Mac Pw Auth Fail

Tags: postgresql, sql-server-localdb, bash, macos

Disclaimer: I am new to MacOs. Haven't found any useful related question.

After successfully installing postgresql 13.2 via homebrew on MacOs 11.2.1 (BigSur) i run into the following problem:

Use terminal for the command

```
psql postgres
```

Prompts user pwd of my standard Mac user account.

Returns:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "standarduser"
```

Try:

```
sudo psql postgres
```

Now asks standard user pwd and accepts it.
Then asks root user pwd and rejects it with the same error as before:
Returns:

```
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try `sudo psql postgres postgres`

Comment: I did, thanks. Unfortunately now I need to provide a pw for the user postgres which I don't have and the pg_hba.config file I only find with .sample at the end of the file name. If that is the correct one, I am not sure what to include to be able to login. Any idea?

Comment: super user don't need a password, they are used to administrate the server, so i really don't undersatand where a password came from. A reinstall perhaps?